# How to disable DialogFlow history/log?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, chatbot, dialogflow-es

I see that dialog flow saves the history of conversation.
How to disable that? I need to have below history table always empty.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click on the gear icon to select the settings, then scroll down to "Log interactions to Dialogflow" and turn this setting off. Then save the settings.

[image]

Comment: It looks like these log settings have been removed in the latest version, is there another way to do it?

Comment: Although the "v1" option has been removed, I still see the two log options that I pointed to in a brand new project. If you're still having issues, create a new SO question and post a picture with what you're seeing that is causing the problem.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your response Prisoner. I have realised that this option isn't available if you are logged into the agent as a "Developer", but once I logged into the agent as the owner the option was available. So if anyone else comes across this with the same issue, make sure you are logged in as the agent "Owner"